# Can I reliably predict that for a single component, `useEffect` callbacks, when available to execute, execute in top-down order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I reliably predict that for a single component, `useEffect` callbacks, when available to execute, execute in top-down order?

*Very simple test*

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2);
  }, []);

  return <div></div>
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-star-du2jx?file=/src/App.js:0-52)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As [the docs say](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns):

> React will apply every effect used by the component, in the order they were specified.